# What event is associated with zooming an interactive matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling

As I understand it, when a user interacts with an interactive `matplotlib` plot (i.e. by clicking, pressing a key, etc.), an [`Event`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.Event) is triggered, which can be [linked to an arbitrary callback function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html#event-connections), if desired.

Interactive `matplotlib` plots often come with a navigation toolbar that includes certain features like zooming and rubberband selection. My question is, is there a way to watch for these things from the backend and react when a user performs one of these actions using the nav bar/mouse?

I have gone through the list of event names on the [event handling page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html) of matplotlib's documentation, as well as looked over the API reference for the [`NavigationToolbar2`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.NavigationToolbar2) class, but I haven't been able to find any connection between the two. Is an event even the thing to be looking for, or is there some other way to detect these kinds of interactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved on my own. In addition to the event types and the `fig.canvas.mpl_connect()` syntax shown on the ["event handling" documentation page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html#event-connections), you can also associate a callback function with an `Axes` instance directly, and this way has some different kinds of events that can be used as triggers. The [API reference for the `Axes` class](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#the-axes-class) has this to say:

> The [`Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) instance supports callbacks through a callbacks attribute which is a [`CallbackRegistry`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cbook_api.html#matplotlib.cbook.CallbackRegistry) instance. The events you can connect to are 'xlim_changed' and 'ylim_changed' and the callback will be called with *func(ax)* where *ax* is the [`Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) instance.

...and then the syntax to connect these axis events to a user-defined callback `func` on an existing axis instance `ax` might look something like this:

```py
def func(axes):
    print("New axis y-limits are", axes.get_ylim())

cb_registry = ax.callbacks
cid = cb_registry.connect('ylim_changed', func)
```

The same approach could be used to watch for x-axis changes as well.